# HTML/CSS: Need help fixing my website

Tags: html, css

I am having some issues with getting my background img to show up on my website or how to fix the label box in col#1 to match the width of the website.
I ran out of ideas how to tweak my website to achieve the desired display look.
The fonts and text are just placeholders in my own version, but here is my code:

```css
body {
  background-image: url("taustakuva.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left bottom;
  width: 560px;
}
#content {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #e3f6fc;
  border-style: solid;
  border-widtH: 5px;
  border-color: #add8e6;
}
#header {
  padding: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
  margin: 0;
  color: green;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #add8e6;
}
form {
  width: 100%;
}
p.subheader {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}
button {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 43px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 128px;
}
#col1 {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100% margin: auto;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #e3f6fc;
}
#col2 {
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 240px;
  float: left;
}
#col3 {
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  witdh: 200px;
  float: left;
}
#hakubutton {
  background-image: url(hakunappi.png);
  display: block;
}
#footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="header">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
  </div>

  <div id="content">

    <div id="col1">
      <form method="post" action="">
        <label for="name">Lorem ipsum</label>
        <input type="text" value="" />
        <br/>

    </div>

    <p class="subheader">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>


    <div id="col2">

      <form action="index.php">
        Lorem ipsum
        <select name="type">
          <option value="skycraper" selected>Lorem ipsum</option>
          <option value="own">Lorem ipsum</option>
          <option value="2floor">Lorem ipsum</option>
          <option value="hotel">Lorem ipsum</option>
        </select>
        <br/>
        <br/>Lorem ipsum
        <select name="mode">
          <option value="solar">Lorem ipsum</option>
          <option value="wood">Lorem ipsum</option>
          <option value="longdistance" selected>Lorem ipsum</option>
          <option value="noheat">Lorem ipsum</option>
        </select>
        <br/>
        <br/>Lorem ipsum
        <select name="rooms">
          <option value="1" selected>1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
        </select>
        <br/>
        <br/>Lorem ipsum
        <select name="size">
          <option value="30" selected>30</option>
          <option value="40">40</option>
          <option value="50">50</option>
          <option value="60">60</option>
        </select>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div id="col3">

      <form action="index.php">

        <label for="name">Lorem ipsum</label>
        <input type="text" value="" />
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <label for="name">Lorem ipsum</label>
        <input type="text" value="" />
        <br/>
        <br/>Lorem ipsum
        <select name="condition">
          <option value="bad" selected>Lorem ipsum</option>
          <option value="ok">Lorem ipsum</option>
          <option value="good">Hyvä</option>
        </select>
        <br/>
        <br/>m2
        <input type="radio" name="ownership" value="rent">Lorem ipsum
        <input type="radio" name="ownership" value="own">Lorem ipsum
        <br>
      </form>
      <br/>


      </form>
    </div>

    <button id="hakubutton">
    </button>

    <div id="footer">


    </div>




  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

in short:

Here is my website:
https://gyazo.com/b40f0e2298e6e42a03ae71b09c7ee805
and here is what I am trying to achieve:
https://gyazo.com/c35099cd12d512686e0b559cf6bc5620

Comment: Please create a working fiddle or pen from your code.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behaviour, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. This is necessary not only to make verification and debugging of the problem as straightforward as possible for us, but also to preserve the validity of the question, once the problem is fixed on the live website. See how to create a [mcve]. In addition to that, the current title does absolutely not describe your issue. Could you please use a more descriptive one? :)

Comment: Also, "here is my website" doesn not lead to a website made from html and css, but just to an image.

Comment: As @Siguza commented. Try to be as clear as possible with the approach of well researched question.

Answer (score 0):

you are expected to put quote within the url for background image in css
    body{
    background-image: url(taustakuva.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left bottom;
    width: 560px;
    }
Then for the second question, please note that the code below comes first in your css page

```
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 100%;
}
```

I am sure this answers your questions.